# How to display a PHP string "AS IS" (special chars inside)?

Tags: php, html, string, echo, special-characters

It is probably a simple question but I don't find an "easy" solution.

I have a PHP string containing exactly these chars :

```
<code>
<language>
Test string
</language>
<content>for(i&lt;10)</content>
</code>
```

I just want to display this string AS IS (char by char) to put it in a textarea.
I have tried htmlentities, htmlspecialchar of course but it is clearly not what I want.

If I use basic "echo", the `&lt;` is replaced by '<'. This is the problem !

Comment: htmlspecialchar should be the right function. Can you show the code that you used?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is fine

Comment: Have you tried setting flags for correct htmlspecialchars use? http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: I think you are outputting exactly those characters, can you verify by viewing the source of your html document? In a browser, it's expected that &lt; would be "replaced" by "<", but you need to look at the plaintext output to verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars` is the right choice, even in a `textarea`.

```
<?php echo "<textarea>" . htmlspecialchars($str) . "</textarea>";
```

works.

Comment: Thx, it was a bad use of htmlspecialchars ! ;)